# How Can I Copy Files From A Matching Directory Structure?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory which contains a sub-set of files from another directory.
I want to replace all of the sub-set files with the files from the other directory.

e.g. a directory structure like this

```
 |-base
 | |-jboss
 | | |-standalone
 | | | |-configuration
 | | | | |-mgmt-users.properties.xml
 | | |-bin
 | | | |-standalone.conf.bat
 | | | |-standalone.conf

 |-override
 | |-jboss
 | | |-standalone
 | | | |-configuration
 | | | | |-mgmt-users.properties.xml
 | | | |-bin
 | | | | |-standalone.conf
```

In this simple case all the files from the `base` directory would be copied to the `override` directory *except* for the standalone.conf.bat since that doesn't exist in the override dir.

My first instinct is to iterate over the override dir and look for an equivalent file in the base dir and copy it.

However, I don't really know how to do that though or even if it is a good way to do it.

What would be a good way to do this on a linux server using bash?

Comment: Use the `find` command to iterate over all the files in `override`. Then just replace `override` with `base` to get the corresponding filename in the `base` directory, and copy it.

Comment: `rsync` might be able to do it.

Comment: different directory structure makes it a bit tricky!

Comment: It is the same directory structure it is just the root of each are in different places